# Can I see my gem version history?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, version, history

I ran `bundle update`, and something broke in my app because of one specific gem. I want to revert back to whatever version of that gem I was using before, but I don't know what the version number was. Is there a way I can check what gem versions I was using previously?

Comment: Did you use any form of version control (git, svn, etc)? Did you have your `Gemfile.lock` in said version control?

Comment: @JustinWood Awesome, I didn't know that Gemfile.lock had the versions in it. Thank you! If you write an answer I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Gemfile.lock` that is generated by `bundler` stores the gem version numbers along with all of its dependencies version numbers.